# Make loop synchronous node js web-kit

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-webkit

My app node.js webkit aim to scan each proxy a file.txt and say if the proxy work.
But i have a probleme when my for is launch, he don't wait the end of test "http.get" on the line 9.
When my first line is tested my var n is on the last line of the file.txt
How wait the end of the test line 11 before continue the loop ?

```
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i].path;
    content = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF-8");
    var lines = content.split("\n");
    for (var n = 0; n < lines.length; n++)
    {
        var arr = lines[n].split(":");

        http.get({host: arr[0], port: arr[1], path: "http://www.google.fr", agent: false}, function(res, req) {
            console.log(req);
            if(res.statusCode == 200){
                el.className = '';
                el.innerHTML = arr[0] + ':' + arr[1] + '\n';
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can use a counter in the http.get callback and call it using "[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)" to preserve your data in each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter in the http.get callback and call it using "bind" to preserve your data in each call.

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i].path;
content = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF-8");
var lines = content.split("\n");
var counter = 0;
var callback = function(res, req) {
  console.log(req);
  if(res.statusCode == 200){
    el.className = '';
    el.innerHTML = this[0] + ':' + this[1] + '\n';
  }
  counter++;
  if(counter == lines.length) {
    //do whatever you wanna do after all calls
  }
};
for (var n = 0; n < lines.length; n++){
    var arr = lines[n].split(":");
    http.get({
      host: arr[0], 
      port: arr[1], 
      path: "http://www.google.fr", 
      agent: false
    }, callback.bind(arr));
}
```

Comment: if you do "console.log(this)" in the callback, does it always show the same data or it shows the correct values?

Comment: Oh sorry, the app work i have miss to change my config. Thank's, i valid your answer. But can you explain the David Mulder method ? i want to try this.

Comment: you can read the `async.each` code [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L118) ...  in case you wonder ... the `_each` code is [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L44) ... it's very similar to my answer but wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

Here is David's answer in detail:

```
var async = require('async');   // make sure you install async (do "npm install async" from command line)
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i].path;
content = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF-8");
var lines = content.split("\n");

async.each(lines, function(line, callback) {
    var arr = line.split(":");

    http.get({host: arr[0], port: arr[1], path: "http://www.google.fr", agent: false}, function(res, req) {
        console.log(req);
        if(res.statusCode == 200){
            el.className = '';
            el.innerHTML = arr[0] + ':' + arr[1] + '\n';
        }
        callback();
    });

},function(){
  console.log("done");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to take a look at the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. It has a large number of functions to handle the asynchronous nature of javascript. Specifically you would want to use the [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function.

To give you a bit of an idea take a look at this:

```
async.each(..., function( file, callback) {
  http.get(...,function(){
   callback();
  });
},function(){
  console.log("done");
});
```

Or if you want to do one after another use `async.eachLimit` with a limit of `1`.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your method, i have see this way for making my loop synchronious. But i'm a beginer, i have trouble to implemente the async.each method on my code. Can i have your help with explication for understand how that work ? Thank's

Comment: @Ricoxor: Just got back now, Ben wrote an example with the full code how it would look using async, although I am confused by what exactly your intended workflow is, so if you want to make it synchronous you would have to replace `each` with `eachLimit` and add the second argument as `1`.